# Error code 500 when calling API from client

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a Lambda function and when I call it from my React app I get the following 2 errors:

`POST https://x7429ccke5.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/sites 500`

and

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:78)`

I do not have a log in system on my website yet so I want to call the api without needed permission so on my serverless.yml, I have it as

```
functions:
  # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in create.js
  # - path: url path is /notes
  # - method: POST request
  # - cors: enabled CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) for browser cross
  #     domain api call
  # - authorizer: authenticate using the AWS IAM role
  createSite:
    handler: CreateSite.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: sites
          method: post
          cors: true
          arn: "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:106845550704:x7429ccke5/*/POST/sites"
```

Comment: Can please elaborate the issue. Its very hard to comprehend what you want to do and what is happening !

Comment: Sorry, on my client I am calling a POST api function when i submit a form. I have the aws lambda function deployed but it is returning the 500 error, although when i test it in the aws console, it works fine

Comment: When I click on the error i get a message saying "missing authentication token" but in aws i set the authentication to "none"

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting the problem is with API Gateway's integration with lambda. It's your API Gateway that is throwing the 500 error. Please check if your API Gateway is staged or not. If it's staged then check for this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/amazon-api-gateway-using-stage-variables.html#call-api-http-backend-via-stage-variable

Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Still didnt work. I am also using postman to try and test it and getting the same error